# Key generation for the Hash function returns a minas values for larger size strings

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm want to generate key values for strings. And this key is going to be used in a hash function. In this case i use ASCII values of characters in generating the key. My method works properly for shorter words. But the thing is when i generate a key for a word about 20 characters it returns a minus value. How can I fix this. My code segment is as below.

```
    public static long genKey(String s) {
    long key = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);

        if (i == 0) {

            key += ch;

        } else {

            int factor = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                factor = factor * 25;

            }
            key += ch * factor;

        }

    }
    return key;

}
```

Can someone help me.
Thank You !

Comment: Why not just use `s.hashCode()`? Is it a requirement that you don't?

Comment: `s.hashCode()` returns an `int`, as well as being often negative.  It looks like OP wants a `long`.

Comment: I want impliment hash map by my self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change

```
 key += ch * factor;
```

to

```
 key += Math.abs(ch * factor);
```

then you'll only be adding positive values to `key`, so `key` will end up positive.  Does this meet your need?

Comment: There can still be integer overflows for addition, also Math.abs(Long.MIN_VALUE) < 0, so it would still have a weird edge case some times.

Comment: I thought about that.  But you can't get `MIN_VALUE` by multiplying a character-sized number by 25 over and over.  So there is NO weird edge case at all.

Comment: yah. Its working. I just want to use this for strings of length about 20 characters. This works properly for even the length of 30 characters. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can still have integer overflow in the addition step, also ch * a large positive number can still be negative, so there are plenty of overflow edge cases

Comment: @MWB There can't be integer overflows in the addition.  You're adding `int` values to a `long`.  You'd need to have a `String` of over 4 billion characters before this could be a problem.

Comment: Your last point about the multiplication is valid though.  I should have written `Math.abs(ch * factor);`.  I will edit it now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is the negative value necessarily a bad thing?  Note that `factor` will overflow the signed 32-bit `int` type within 8 characters - this overflow will result in a "negative" value if the value is too large for 31 bits and the 32nd bit is set:

```
scala> 25 * 25 * 25 * 25 * 25 * 25 * 25
res0: Int = 1808548329

scala> 25 * 25 * 25 * 25 * 25 * 25 * 25 * 25
res1: Int = -2030932031
```

If you insist on having a positive value for `factor`, then before adding it to `key` the value either call `Math.abs(factor)` to get the absolute value, or use a bitwise AND to mask off the sign bit: `factor & 0x7FFFFFFF`.